# Merge javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me to create a single script merging these two?
The first script is included in my menù bar that is included in all pages of my site. Contains the buttons for Print, Excel and PDF, landscape print and Italian language for my bootstrap tables. The second that i would include into the first is for single column search into the tables.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $('#example').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',      
            buttons: [
                // Stampa in orizzontale
                { extend: "print", text: ' Stampa', className: 'btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-print',
                    customize: function(win)
                    {

                        var last = null;
                        var current = null;
                        var bod = [];

                        var css = '@page { size: landscape; }',
                            head = win.document.head || win.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                            style = win.document.createElement('style');

                        style.type = 'text/css';
                        style.media = 'print';

                        if (style.styleSheet)
                        {
                          style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          style.appendChild(win.document.createTextNode(css));
                        }

                        head.appendChild(style);
                    }
                },  
                { extend: 'excelHtml5', text: ' Esporta Excel', className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt' },            
                { extend: 'pdfHtml5', text: ' Esporta PDF', className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-file' }
            ],
            "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Italian.json"
            }
        });
    });

</script>   

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Cerca '+title+'" />' );
        } );

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();

        // Apply the search
        table.columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove extra script tag and document ready function as below.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {          
        $('#example').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',      
            buttons: [
                // Stampa in orizzontale
                { extend: "print", text: ' Stampa', className: 'btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-print',
                    customize: function(win)
                    {

                        var last = null;
                        var current = null;
                        var bod = [];

                        var css = '@page { size: landscape; }',
                            head = win.document.head || win.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
                            style = win.document.createElement('style');

                        style.type = 'text/css';
                        style.media = 'print';

                        if (style.styleSheet)
                        {
                          style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          style.appendChild(win.document.createTextNode(css));
                        }

                        head.appendChild(style);
                    }
                },  
                { extend: 'excelHtml5', text: ' Esporta Excel', className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt' },            
                { extend: 'pdfHtml5', text: ' Esporta PDF', className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-file' }
            ],
            "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Italian.json"
            }
        });


        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
            var title = $(this).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Cerca '+title+'" />' );
        } );

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();

        // Apply the search
        table.columns().every( function () {
            var that = this;

            $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
                if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                    that
                        .search( this.value )
                        .draw();
                }
            } );
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Without '''// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
   $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Cerca '+title+'" />' );
   } );''' the single column search box don't appear